# How do I display data from Multiple Google sheets using JSON feed URL

Tags: json, angularjs, google-sheets, angularjs-http

I'm able to display results and search for data from spreadsheet which has only one sheet. Using od6 as JSON URL : var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/153Obe1TdWlIPyveZoNxEw53rdrghHsiWU9l-WgGwCrE/od6/public/values?alt=json";

My requirement is to fetch JSON feed from multiple sheets like blow URL's
//var url1 = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1OJX_UfZ7KQ-NMKcpXmYT8Ml1OfzerPnmUyEcSoMqeZc/2/public/values?alt=json"; // I tried with one URL sheet but still not able to display can you please help 
//var url2 = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1OJX_UfZ7KQ-NMKcpXmYT8Ml1OfzerPnmUyEcSoMqeZc/3/public/values?alt=json";

```
<html>
    <head>


<script src="menu.js"></script>      
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Json file : https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1OJX_UfZ7KQ-NMKcpXmYT8Ml1OfzerPnmUyEcSoMqeZc/public/basic?alt=json

// code for displaying the data in tabs
 // Json file : https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1OJX_UfZ7KQ-NMKcpXmYT8Ml1OfzerPnmUyEcSoMqeZc/public/basic?alt=json

function openPage(pageName,elmnt) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.color = "#969595";

  }

  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
  elmnt.style.color = "white";

}


    //angular js code to display search in JSON URL data

   var app= angular.module('sample', []);
 app.controller('sampleController', function ($scope, $http) {              
   var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/153Obe1TdWlIPyveZoNxEw53rdrghHsiWU9l-WgGwCrE/od6/public/values?alt=json";
     //var url1 = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1OJX_UfZ7KQ-NMKcpXmYT8Ml1OfzerPnmUyEcSoMqeZc/2/public/values?alt=json"; // Using url1 instead of url is not working
     //var url2 = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1OJX_UfZ7KQ-NMKcpXmYT8Ml1OfzerPnmUyEcSoMqeZc/3/public/values?alt=json";
    //var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1OJX_UfZ7KQ-NMKcpXmYT8Ml1OfzerPnmUyEcSoMqeZc/1/public/values?alt=json"; // url for sheet1

    $http.get(url)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {     
         $scope.users = data.feed.entry;
         //console.log($scope.users);
    })
    .error(function(error, status, headers, config) {
         console.log(status);
         console.log("Error occured");
    }); 
   app.filter('highlightFilter', $sce =>
 function (element, searchInput) {
   element = element.replace(new RegExp(`(${searchInput})`, 'gi'),
             '<span class="highlighted">$&</span>');
   return $sce.trustAsHtml(element);
 });
    $scope.search='';
    $scope.searchFilter=function(item){

        if(item.gsx$topic.$t.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.search.toLowerCase()) != -1 || item.gsx$response.$t.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.search.toLowerCase()) != -1){
        // code to highlight

      // code to highlight
        return true;

            }
      return false;
    }

});   


</script>


    </head>
<body>


<div ng-app="sample"  ng-controller="sampleController">



  <input type="text" name="search" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search in all sheets" ></input>

    <br>
    <br>
  <table  style="border: 1px solid black ;" >
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:blue; font-size:14px;"><center><b>Question</b></center></td>
            <td style="color:blue; font-size:14px;"><center><b>Response</b></center></td>
        </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:searchFilter">
        <td style="border: 1px solid black ; width:30%;white-space: pre-wrap;">{{user.gsx$topic.$t}}</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black ; width:70%;white-space: pre-wrap;">{{user.gsx$response.$t}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello @TejoSaiKumarEEPU, are you getting any errors? Cheers!

Comment: Hi @ale13 I'm getting below error while using url1. Also my requirement is to get data and display from all sheets with sheet names. can you help? Error : userCodeAppPanel:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: can someone help with this error? I have used http.get(url1) and http.get(url2) and so on.. to access multiple sheets data and I'm getting the data from my personal G-sheet. But not able to get from the original file that is from my corporate account.